# Calculate ground track from CCSDS OEM

Tags: orbital-elements, two-line-elements

Are there open source solutions (preferable Python) to calculate the ground track of a spacecraft (i.e. in latitute/longitude) from [CCSDS OEM](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/502x0b2c1.pdf) (orbit ephemeris message) format (which is a dataset of epochs and associated position vectors)?

Alternatively, one could get lat/lon from TLE via pyehpem or other libraries. Then the question would be: how to convert OEM to TLE?

Comment: It would be nice to have a link that helps readers know what CCSDS OEM's are. I found these [blue book](http://mtc-m16c.sid.inpe.br/col/sid.inpe.br/mtc-m18@80/2009/07.17.14.59/doc/CCSDS%20502.0-B-02.pdf) and [pink book](https://cwe.ccsds.org/moims/docs/MOIMS-NAV/Draft%20Documents/Orbit%20Data%20Messages%20(ODM)/ODM%20Archive/502x0p0.6-changestracked.pdf) links, but no idea if they are optimal or what the reference to color means. This [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14268/12102) and its answer also have outdated OEM links.

Comment: Update: COLOR definitions on page 7: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100042149.pdf

Comment: You should not need to convert to TLE. Converting an ephemeris to TLE is not an easy task and you can probably get better results if you convert from orbital elements (that you will use when generating tle) to lat/long directly. Since I do not know anything about CCSDS, if you are okay with TLE level accuracy, I can suggest you to get epoch time from CCSDS and get corresponding TLE's from space-track.org to find lat/long based on those TLEs.

Comment: @uhoh, I added the CCSDS link.  BTW, Blue Books are the official accepted standard.  Any other color is in some stage of review/acceptance.